# Unable to expand view header file with frameworks in Xcode12

Tags: xcode, xcode12

[image: 1]

I wanted to look at the list of header files for the Framework, but Xcode12 doesn't seem to support expanding the Framework

Comment: Is this a bug in xcode12, why does no one know? I checked a lot of information and there is no solution. I saw the post on the official forum, but no one responded [How to expanding Framework in Xcod… | Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661494)

Comment: Today I experienced this issue too with Xcode 12.2. While opening an existing Xcode 11.7 project, all frameworks are shown with the white LEGO-like block icon and can not be expanded to view the header files. Nothing on the internet can be found about this, except this post and the referred link to the unanswered Apple Forum thread. Are we alone?

Answer (score 0):

For frameworks in pod, you can try add this to podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      dir = project.path + "../#{target.name}"
      if Dir.exist?(dir)
        Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*.framework") do |p|
          group = project.pod_group(target.name)
          headersDir = "#{p}/Headers"
          if Dir.exist?(headersDir)
            project.add_file_reference(headersDir, group, true)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```